# Color change in textview

Tags: android, textview

I am using XML parser.in that i have to change the color of the textview according to the value coming from the API.

From api it will return either 1 or -1 (for me if it is 1 means i have to change the background as green,otherwise red).

How can i do that.

Answer (score 3):

simple...

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

int response = responseFromParse(); // your parser logic

if(response == 1){
    yourTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);    
}else{    
    yourTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rashmi.I have one more doubt.In my case i am storing the value got from API in an Hashmap,in that how can i check the valu from hash map equals to 1 or not.I tried this if(map.get(KEY_DIRECTION).contains("1"))  but it is not working.

Comment: is your Hashmap is <String,String> or <Integer, String> ??

Comment: try this  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("response", "1");
  String response = map.get("response"); // this gives response = "1234"
  if(response.equals("1")){
   System.out.println("go..");
   
  }

Comment: mark answer as correct if it is helpful.. otherwise it goes in the list of unanswered questions..

Comment: Hi rashmi   map.put(KEY_DIRECTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DIRECTION));      String dir=map.get(KEY_DIRECTION);
  if(dir.equals("1"))
  {
   System.out.print("dir=");
   description_label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }                But it is not going into the If condition,showing force to close error.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
if(API()==1)
    textView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
else
    textView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the returm value is in string try

`TextView txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01);`

`String k;`

`if(k.contentEquals("1")){`

```
 `txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`
```

`}`

`else{`

```
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
int val=Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString());
if(val==1)
   txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
else if(val==-1)
   txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView text_view =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

```
int returnval= your_returnval();

if(returnval== 1){

    text_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 

}
else if(returnval== -1){   

    text_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);    
}
```